# Kubernetes Service Account Token has super power?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-apiserver, k8s-serviceaccount

I accidentally was checking if my pod had the right `ServiceAccount` and its Bindings. Out of curiosity I wanted to check if the token created from this service account is bound with the certain `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` which are read only. I tried few things from [Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#without-kubectl-proxy), and I am afraid my understanding is somewhat wrong. Please help me to understand this correctly.

I used existing `ClusterRole` `view` and associated to my service account `my-sa` as `ClusterRoleBinding`.

```
APISERVER=$(kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.server}')

SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get serviceaccount my-sa -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')

TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret $SECRET_NAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode)
```

Then I use the `TOKEN` to talk to `APISERVER` for creating a pod in test namespace

```
curl -X POST $APISERVER/api/v1/namespaces/test/pods\?fieldManager=kubectl-run 
-d '{"kind":"Pod",
     "apiVersion":"v1",
     "metadata":
       { "name":"nginx",
         "creationTimestamp":null,
         "labels":{"run":"nginx"}
       },
      "spec": 
          { "containers":
            [ 
              { "name":"nginx",
                "image":"nginx",
                "resources":{}
              } 
            ],
         "restartPolicy":"Always",
         "dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst"
     },
    "status":{}
  }' --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" --header "Accept: application/json, */*" --insecure
```

What Happened

1. This created a successful pod and this token moreoever can create anything.
2. I even tried to use the `default ServiceAccount` from the `default` namespace and the behavior is same

My Understanding.

1. This token was associated with the `ClusterRole` of `View` hence it should not have allowed the token to create any resource.
2. Isnt this a loophole because if I am able to get the ServiceAccount Token from a client code and pass it outside the cluster?

My Setup: Docker Desktop Kubernetes.

Please help me in understanding what is incorrect in this. I am unable to understand the scope of the `ServiceAccount` token. I tried to google on this but I couldnt find it. Probably I did not have the right set of words to find it.

EDIT-1:

Describing ClusterRole View.

```
    Name:         view
Labels:       kubernetes.io/bootstrapping=rbac-defaults
              rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit=true
Annotations:  rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: true
PolicyRule:
  Resources                                    Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                                    -----------------  --------------  -----
  bindings                                     []                 []              [get list watch]
  configmaps                                   []                 []              [get list watch]
  endpoints                                    []                 []              [get list watch]
  events                                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  limitranges                                  []                 []              [get list watch]
  namespaces/status                            []                 []              [get list watch]
  namespaces                                   []                 []              [get list watch]
  persistentvolumeclaims/status                []                 []              [get list watch]
  persistentvolumeclaims                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  pods/log                                     []                 []              [get list watch]
  pods/status                                  []                 []              [get list watch]
  pods                                         []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicationcontrollers/scale                 []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicationcontrollers/status                []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicationcontrollers                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  resourcequotas/status                        []                 []              [get list watch]
  resourcequotas                               []                 []              [get list watch]
  serviceaccounts                              []                 []              [get list watch]
  services/status                              []                 []              [get list watch]
  services                                     []                 []              [get list watch]
  controllerrevisions.apps                     []                 []              [get list watch]
  daemonsets.apps/status                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  daemonsets.apps                              []                 []              [get list watch]
  deployments.apps/scale                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  deployments.apps/status                      []                 []              [get list watch]
  deployments.apps                             []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicasets.apps/scale                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicasets.apps/status                      []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicasets.apps                             []                 []              [get list watch]
  statefulsets.apps/scale                      []                 []              [get list watch]
  statefulsets.apps/status                     []                 []              [get list watch]
  statefulsets.apps                            []                 []              [get list watch]
  horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling/status  []                 []              [get list watch]
  horizontalpodautoscalers.autoscaling         []                 []              [get list watch]
  cronjobs.batch/status                        []                 []              [get list watch]
  cronjobs.batch                               []                 []              [get list watch]
  jobs.batch/status                            []                 []              [get list watch]
  jobs.batch                                   []                 []              [get list watch]
  daemonsets.extensions/status                 []                 []              [get list watch]
  daemonsets.extensions                        []                 []              [get list watch]
  deployments.extensions/scale                 []                 []              [get list watch]
  deployments.extensions/status                []                 []              [get list watch]
  deployments.extensions                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  ingresses.extensions/status                  []                 []              [get list watch]
  ingresses.extensions                         []                 []              [get list watch]
  networkpolicies.extensions                   []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicasets.extensions/scale                 []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicasets.extensions/status                []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicasets.extensions                       []                 []              [get list watch]
  replicationcontrollers.extensions/scale      []                 []              [get list watch]
  ingresses.networking.k8s.io/status           []                 []              [get list watch]
  ingresses.networking.k8s.io                  []                 []              [get list watch]
  networkpolicies.networking.k8s.io            []                 []              [get list watch]
  poddisruptionbudgets.policy/status           []                 []              [get list watch]
  poddisruptionbudgets.policy                  []                 []              [get list watch]
```

Comment: Describe your clusterrole to see what all it is allowing

Comment: @RakeshGupta added to the question

Comment: ok here lies the problem
 https://www.portainer.io/blog/docker-desktop-kubernetes-not-enforcing-rbac-rules

and here lies the fix: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4774

Comment: I will update my answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Summary of [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3694) from [Neil Cresswell on portainer.io](https://www.portainer.io/blog/docker-desktop-kubernetes-not-enforcing-rbac-rules)

By default, Docker Desktop and their embedded Kubernetes offering does **NOT** enforce any RBAC rules. It will let you create RBAC rules, but it wont enforce them.

**ALL** service accounts automatically receive **cluster-admin** role **BY DEFAULT**.

The article says this can be easily fixed by running `kubectl delete clusterrolebinding docker-for-desktop-binding` and it will start enforcing RBAC rules.

You can also [patch this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4774#issuecomment-658128960) on your own deploys by running:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: docker-for-desktop-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: system:serviceaccounts:kube-system
EOF
```

Comment: ok you elaborated the same answer that I posted in comment ;) Nice one

Comment: Thanks. Also thanks for sharing your problem and providing valuable insight to community :)